# How to set a struct member of type string

Tags: c, pointers, string, struct

I have a struct which contains a member called char *text.  After I've created an object from the struct, then how do I set text to a string?

Comment: objects in C?, strings in C? I think you need to clarify your question a little bit more :)

Comment: @HyLian: Objects in C? Yes, in C all data in storage is referred to as "objects". Strings in C? There are strings in C, of course.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your struct is like

```
 struct phenom_struct {
    char * text;
 };
```

and you allocate it

```
 struct phenom_struct * ps = malloc (sizeof (phenom_struct));
```

then after checking the value of `ps` is not NULL (zero), which means "failure", you can set text to a string like this:

```
 ps->text = "This is a string";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
typedef struct myStruct
{
    char *text;
}*MyStruct;

int main()
{
    int len = 50;
    MyStruct s = (MyStruct)malloc(sizeof MyStruct);
    s->text = (char*)malloc(len * sizeof char);
    strcpy(s->text, "a string whose length is less than len");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your struct member is not really a string, but a pointer. You can set the pointer to another string by

```
o.text = "Hello World";
```

But you must be careful, the string must live at least as long as the object. Using malloc as shown in the other answers is a possible way to do that. In many cases, it's more desirable to use a char array in the struct; i.e. instead of

```
struct foobar {
    ...
    char *text;
}
```

use

```
struct foobar {
    ...
    char text[MAXLEN];
}
```

which obviously requires you to know the maximum length of the string.

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
struct Foo {
    char* text;
};

Foo f;
f.text = "something";

// or
f.text = strdup("something"); // create a copy
// use the f.text ...
free(f.text); // free the copy
```